# moving from hogan to angular after data received from server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, hogan.js

I've set my `app.engine` to hogan and i am using express router so this is how i used to present data:

```
   router.get('/upcoming_events', securePages, function(req, res, next){
            res.render('upcoming_events', {title: 'Welcome to aDating - Upcoming Events', users:users});
    })
```

and in my HTML page i would access the data like this
<`h2>{{users}}</h2>`

now the thing is `{{users}}` contains a Json formatted content and i want to process it with angular...how can i do this?? thx

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(valid_json);` will turn your json string into a JS object.

---

To elaborate, this is what it could look like if you were using `$http` to fetch the data from your Express app.

```
$scope.getStuff = function () {
  $http.get(apiHost + '/upcoming_events').then(function (res) {
    return JSON.parse(res.data.upcoming_events);
    // { title: 'Welcome to aDating - Upcoming Events', users: [ /** a collection of users, I presume? **/ ] }
  });
};
```